# What makes the Sacred Combo so sacred?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

During a Stream of SSBM, I watched what the commentaters called a "Sacred Combo." But, why is this combo so hyped over, and how does one pull it off?

Captain Falcon and Fox were used to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Smashpedia:](https://supersmashbros.fandom.com/wiki/Falcon_Punch#Combos_into_Falcon_Punch)

> **Sacred Combo**
> A combo that uses Captain Falcon's Forward Aerial and the Falcon Punch. Very hard to perform.

> The combo itself is performed by knocking an opponent off the stage with Captain Falcon's forward aerial (the Knee Smash) and then jumping off the edge of the stage before striking the opponent with Captain Falcon's neutral B, the Falcon Punch, in mid-air. If performed successfully, this combo results in a KO in almost all cases, although by performing this combo, Captain Falcon may fail to recover back to the stage in Melee if he jumps too far off the edge to perform his Falcon Punch. In either cases, KOing an opponent with the Sacred Combo is widely regarded as being one of the most satisfying ways to remove an opponent's stock.

Here is a quick example:

[image: animated GIF]

It's essentially just a very high-risk, high-reward move to pull.

Comment: Is the hitstun really long enough to make it a true combo?